# Rock, Paper, Scissors - debugging multiple round game

Tags: javascript

Kindly assist with the completion of the code. Especially with the `game()` function. The problems are listed below.

1. The `computerPlay()` does not change when the loop runs over, it maintains the same answer to the end of the loop.
2. Also, I need the `game()` function to be able to print out the player with the most **WIN OUTPUT**

**WHAT MY CODE DOES**
Because the outputs are the same, it is able to tell the winner after the number of rounds set.
The output is then stored in an `array`.

Kindly note that some of the codes are commented. You can uncomment it to help me modify it if possible or give similar solutions.

```js
//Computer player argorithm
function computerPlay(){
    let comOption = ""
    const guess = Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1;
    let finalAnswer = guess % 3;
    if(finalAnswer > 1){
        comOption = "Rock"; 
    }else if(finalAnswer === 1){
        comOption = "Paper";
    }else if(finalAnswer < 1){
        comOption = "Scissors";
    }
    return comOption;
}

//Single round function
function playRound(computerSelection, playerSelection){
    let ansDeclaration = "";
    var computerWin = `Computer Win! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`;
    var noBodyWin = `Equals ${computerSelection} = ${playerSelection}`;
    var youWin = `You Win! ${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection}`;

    if(playerSelection == "Scissors" && computerSelection == "Paper"){
        ansDeclaration = youWin;
    }else if(playerSelection =="Paper" && computerSelection == "Rock"){
        ansDeclaration = youWin;
    }else if(playerSelection =="Rock" && computerSelection == "Scissors"){
        ansDeclaration = youWin;
    }else if(computerSelection == "Paper" && playerSelection == "Rock"){
        ansDeclaration = computerWin;
    }else if(computerSelection == "Scissors" && playerSelection == "Paper"){
        ansDeclaration = computerWin;
    }else if(computerSelection == "Rock" && playerSelection == "Scissors"){
        ansDeclaration = computerWin;
    }else{
        ansDeclaration = noBodyWin;
    }
    return ansDeclaration;
}

//Creating game function
function game(){
  var computerWin = `Computer Win! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`;
  var noBodyWin = `Equals ${computerSelection} = ${playerSelection}`;
  var youWin = `You Win! ${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection}`;

   const rounds = parseInt(prompt("Enter the number of turns you would like to play the game: "))
   let outComeArr = []; //Outcome of the game in array
    for(let count = 0; count < rounds; count++){
        let outCome = (playRound(computerSelection, playerSelection)); 
        outComeArr.push(outCome);
    }
    for(let count = 0; count < outComeArr.length; count++){
        if(outComeArr[count]=== youWin){
          console.log("Player Win")
        }else if(outComeArr[count] === computerWin){
          console.log("Computer Win")
        }else if(outComeArr[count]=== noBodyWin){
          console.log("Draw Round")
        }
      }
    return outComeArr;
    
    //The code below helps in breaking the array "outComeArray to determine the winner"
   /*  for(let count = 0; count < outComeArr.length; count++){
        if(outComeArr[count] === youWin){
            let countWin = 0;
            countWin++
          console.log(`Player win ${countWin} times`);
        }else if(outComeArr[count]=== computerWin){
          let countWin = 0;
          countWin++;
          console.log(`Computer Win ${countWin} times`);
        }else if(outComeArr[count]=== noBodyWin){
          let countWin = 0;
          countWin++;
          console.log(`Draw Round ${countWin} times`);
        }
      } */
}


const computerSelection = computerPlay();
const playerSelection = "Scissors";
console.log(game());
```

Comment: You need to describe what should the behavior be and why the current behavior is wrong. You would also do well if you did a debugging yourself and shared the results here.

Comment: At the end of your code, see this: `const computerSelection = computerPlay();`. You only let the computer play once. This should be called in the loop (also, maybe use `let`, not `const`?).

Comment: @LajosArpad The code is supposed to run the number of times the user will insert it. If the win of either parties is more than the other, the code should ouput the number of wins and who won. I hope this helps thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you define the moves exactly once at the end of the file. You need to redefine them upon each move. I fixed the issue and also implemented player move for you.

```js
//Computer player argorithm
function computerPlay(){
    let comOption = ""
    const guess = Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1;
    let finalAnswer = guess % 3;
    if(finalAnswer > 1){
        comOption = "Rock"; 
    }else if(finalAnswer === 1){
        comOption = "Paper";
    }else if(finalAnswer < 1){
        comOption = "Scissors";
    }
    return comOption;
}

function playerPlay() {
    let move = prompt("What do you move?");
    if (['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scrissors'].indexOf(move) === -1) move = 'Scrissors';
    return move;
}

//Single round function
function playRound(){
    computerSelection = computerPlay();
    playerSelection = playerPlay();
    let ansDeclaration = "";
    var computerWin = `Computer Win! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`;
    var noBodyWin = `Equals ${computerSelection} = ${playerSelection}`;
    var youWin = `You Win! ${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection}`;

    if(playerSelection == "Scissors" && computerSelection == "Paper"){
        ansDeclaration = youWin;
    }else if(playerSelection =="Paper" && computerSelection == "Rock"){
        ansDeclaration = youWin;
    }else if(playerSelection =="Rock" && computerSelection == "Scissors"){
        ansDeclaration = youWin;
    }else if(computerSelection == "Paper" && playerSelection == "Rock"){
        ansDeclaration = computerWin;
    }else if(computerSelection == "Scissors" && playerSelection == "Paper"){
        ansDeclaration = computerWin;
    }else if(computerSelection == "Rock" && playerSelection == "Scissors"){
        ansDeclaration = computerWin;
    }else{
        ansDeclaration = noBodyWin;
    }
    return ansDeclaration;
}

//Creating game function
function game(){
  var computerWin = `Computer Win! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`;
  var noBodyWin = `Equals ${computerSelection} = ${playerSelection}`;
  var youWin = `You Win! ${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection}`;

   const rounds = parseInt(prompt("Enter the number of turns you would like to play the game: "))
   let outComeArr = []; //Outcome of the game in array
    for(let count = 0; count < rounds; count++){
        let outCome = (playRound()); 
        outComeArr.push(outCome);
    }
    for(let count = 0; count < outComeArr.length; count++){
        if(outComeArr[count]=== youWin){
          console.log("Player Win")
        }else if(outComeArr[count] === computerWin){
          console.log("Computer Win")
        }else if(outComeArr[count]=== noBodyWin){
          console.log("Draw Round")
        }
      }
    return outComeArr;
    
    //The code below helps in breaking the array "outComeArray to determine the winner"
   /*  for(let count = 0; count < outComeArr.length; count++){
        if(outComeArr[count] === youWin){
            let countWin = 0;
            countWin++
          console.log(`Player win ${countWin} times`);
        }else if(outComeArr[count]=== computerWin){
          let countWin = 0;
          countWin++;
          console.log(`Computer Win ${countWin} times`);
        }else if(outComeArr[count]=== noBodyWin){
          let countWin = 0;
          countWin++;
          console.log(`Draw Round ${countWin} times`);
        }
      } */
}


var computerSelection;
var playerSelection;
console.log(game());
```